# Dafny fails in Visual Studio Code on MacOS 10.14.6: Does anyone know where mono is?

Tags: visual-studio-code, mono, dafny

I am not sure if this is a Visual Studio Code issue or  Dafny issue as I am  new to both.
Loaded Visual Studio Code then from within Visual Studio Code loaded the extension for Dafny.
I get the following error message and know that you can tell Visual Studio explicitly where mono is to be found but I do not know where mono is?

[image: Visual Studio Code locked]

```
  verify all1
all verifyfile:///Users/dstr/GoogleDrive/Teaching/SWEN324/FreshStart/fresh.dfy
The verifyer process ended with code 0
Local: 2.3.0
Remote:2.3.0
events.js:180
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn mono EAGAIN
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
  errno: 'EAGAIN',
  code: 'EAGAIN',
  syscall: 'spawn mono',
  path: 'mono',
  spawnargs: [
    '/Users/dstr/.vscode/extensions/correctnesslab.dafny-vscode-0.17.2/dafny/dafny/DafnyServer.exe'
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://www.mono-project.com/

Comment: The problem was solved by turning off the Automatic counter example generator. In the settings for the dafny extension.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by turning off the Automatic counter example generator. In the settings for the dafny extension.
[image: Dafny extension settings]